# Problems with a PHP login for Admin

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having an issue with my code, my login works perfectly but I want it to show a list of users registered to the website from the mysql database when I login as admin@admin.com for my credentials. My code shows a list of users registered for the website but it shows it for every person that logs in now instead of just the admin. Could anyone see what I am missing? Thank you. Code below.

```
    <?php
session_start();


$mysql_hostname = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'username';
$mysql_password = 'password';
$mysql_database = 'db_users2015';

$connect = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
or die ("Couldn't connect");

echo "<BR>Connection Successful";

  //to put data into database
  //select database
  $db_selected= mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $connect) 
  or die ("Couldn't connect to the database");

//frontend and backend data processing
  $email= $_POST['email'];
  $password= $_POST['password'];


//to check for admin

$sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= 'admin@admin.com' and password= 'password'";
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql);
  {echo
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users");
  echo '<table>';
while($rowtwo = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo '<tr>
        <td>' .$rowtwo['email'].'</td>
        </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
} 



//To see if email is registered
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email= '{$_POST['email']}'";
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_result($sql_result, 0)<1)
 {
die("<BR>Email address not found");
}

else{
    echo "Login Successful!";
}



//To check if email and password match

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND 
password ='$password' LIMIT 1");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
  $firstname = $row["firstname"];
  $lastname = $row["lastname"];
  echo "<BR>Welcome back, ";
  echo $firstname;
  echo " ";
  echo $lastname;
}else{   
  echo 'wrong password/username combo';
}

?>
```

Comment: `{` alone don't make a conditional. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php Also why the static values `$sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= 'admin@admin.com' and password= 'password'"`? Don't pass user input directly to your SQL.

Comment: Also default note here about `mysql_` functions being deprecated and not storing passwords in plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an actual conditional.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if( $result->num_rows == 1 ) {
    //show list
}else {
    //not authorized
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are finding the user record that has the admin email address, but you are not comparing that to the person who just logged in. I see curly braces around your table code, but no if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting up some sort of authentication groups.

So if the user logged in is a member of the admin group then they would see admin like things, likewise someone in the site users group would see site users things, etc...